# Convert physical to ESXi machine using VMware vCenter Converter?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

I want to convert a physical machine to a virtual machine using VMware vCenter Converter. According to the product page of VMware vCenter Converter I should be able to create a virtual machine for ESXi, however during the conversion wizard I can only choose various versions of Workstation, Fusion, Player and Server as target type, not ESXi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should choose a destination type of "VMWare Infrastructure virtual machine" and point it to the address of your ESXi server or vCenter server. The result will be a powered-off VM on the ESXi host.

[image]

Comment: The problem is I want to install ESXi on the system that is currently running the physical system. So I want to back it up as a VM first, then install ESXi.

Comment: You can [export to one of the Workstation formats](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1012258), then reconvert the VM/import it into ESXi with vCenter Converter.

Comment: Hmm thanks, seems to be the easiest way. Still complicated though ;-)